# AES/ECB/PKCS5 padding issue in Python

Tags: python, encryption, aes

Here is my code for encryption

```
BS = cryptoAES.block_size
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]


class AESCipher:
def __init__(self):
    self.key = b'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    self.iv = b'123edfr4@#90&65$'
    
def encrypt(self, data):
    cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
    _pad = pad(data).encode('utf-8')
    response = base64.b64encode(self.iv + cipher.encrypt(_pad)).decode('utf-8')
    print('+++++++++++',response)
```

1. Key Size in Bits:256
2. Cipher Mode of Encryption:CBC
3. input : '164386'
4. after encryption output will be: MTIzZWRmcjRAIzkwJjY1JES7OMmdSrtGJX+An1UoVNY=

When I try to decrypt using online tool([tool](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/aes-encryption-decryption)) output will be öÁéáfsÊa×‡ÒH164386.
required output is 164386.

Full code is here:

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Cipher import AES as cryptoAES
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode


class Globals:
    def __init__(self):
        self.KEY = b'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        self.IV = b'123edfr4@#90&65$'


BS = cryptoAES.block_size
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[:-ord(s[len(s)-1:])]


class AESCipher:
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = b'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        self.iv = b'123edfr4@#90&65$'
        
    def encrypt(self, data):
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, self.iv)
        _pad = pad(data).encode('utf-8')
        response = base64.b64encode(self.iv + cipher.encrypt(_pad)).decode('utf-8')
        print('+++++++++++',response)


def test():
    app_id = '164386'
    response = AESCipher().encrypt(app_id)
    return response

output = test()
```

Comment: `MTIzZWRmcjRAIzkwJjY1JES7OMmdSrtGJX+An1UoVNY=` is the Base64 encoded concatenation of IV and ciphertext. On the website, IV and ciphertext must be entered *separately*. If this is done, decryption works as well.

Comment: Can you show an example for this

Comment: Either do not concatenate IV and ciphertext in the Python code or separate both parts for testing on the website, s. https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/zC4

Comment: padding and unpadding should be done only on the plaintext **bytes**, not on the plaintext string. UTF-8 encoding may cause one character to be encoded to multiple bytes, which could make the byte length no longer a multiple of the block size.

Comment: okay, that's working fine now